# find out those points which are intersecting each other using spatial filter in C# arcobjects

Tags: arcobjects

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine overlapping points using a spatial filter in ArcObject](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19249/determine-overlapping-points-using-a-spatial-filter-in-arcobject)

I have a point layer having thousands of point, now what i have to do using Spatial filter i have to find out those points which are intersecting each other. And then objectid of intersecting point should be display in a list box.
in C# Arc Objects

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you run the [Point Distance tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001r000000.htm)  This way you will get the points that are close to each other. This is required, since only in very few cases, will you points that are exactly at the same location.